# Does the Ixalan vampire race's Bloodthirst attack qualify for Sneak Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, racial-traits, sneak-attack, mtg-plane-shift

I am playing a Vampire rogue (the race is from the [*Plane Shift: Ixalan*](https://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/magic/plane-shift_ixalan.pdf) supplement, p. 14). I'm intrigued by the many uses of the Bloodthirst ability. Can you apply Sneak Attack to the bite?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se. When you have time, please take our [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour). The [tag:dnd-5e] tag is enough to indicate the game system, and people already filter/favorite the home page using these tags, so you don't need to put the system in the title. As I have mentioned in my answer, similar to Unearthed Arcana, the content in Plane Shift: Ixalan has a pretty inconsistent and unclear wording, due to not being playtested and refined. Hope my (and other future) answer(s) help you nonetheless.

Answer (score 10):

## RAW, it's unclear, but most likely nope.

Sneak attack:

> Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll. **The attack must use a Finesse or a ranged weapon.**

The Bite from the Ixalan Vampire is a "melee attack", without any specification about being a Finesse weapon attack. The "default" is that weapons **do not have the finesse property**, unless specified.

The Bloodthirst Feature states

> **Bloodthirst**. You can drain blood and life
> energy from a willing creature, or one that is
> grappled by you, incapacitated, or restrained.
> **Make a melee attack against the target**. If you
> hit, you deal 1 piercing damage and 1d6 necrotic
> damage. The target’s hit point maximum
> is reduced by an amount equal to the necrotic
> damage taken, and you regain hit points equal
> to that amount. The reduction lasts until the target
> finishes a long rest. The target dies if this
> effect reduces its hit point maximum to 0.

The emphasized part is the only part that indicates something about the nature of the attack (i.e. it's melee). We are left to wonder about everything else - which led to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124080/43856). It's clear that it is **not** a ranged weapon. As it's similar to a Bite attack, it depends on whether the DM considers the fangs a "finesse weapon" or not. As I said, the default is that they are not, as it is not specified.

---

Note that the [Plane Shift: Ixalan article](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/plane-shift-ixalan-2018-01-09) has the disclaimer

> The game mechanics in this supplement are usable in your D&D campaign but are not fully tempered by playtests and design iterations. For these reasons, material in this supplement is not legal in D&D Organized Play events.

similar to Unearthed Arcana (though with different purposes - UA is supposed to be playtested by the other tables). This means the writing is indeed inconsistent and most of the ruling and interpretation ends up to DM fiat.

Answer (score -4):

As I read it.  I would give them the sneak attack damage that would add to the 1 point of bite damage.  the 1d6 necrotic would stay as 1d6.

As I see it the 1d6 would be drinking the blood, while the bite could be a gingerly nice 1 dmg point bite, or a throat ripped out, or a major arterial vessel was severed inflicting much more damage.  Vampires do no need to bite the neck, they just need to get access to blood so in battle I could see a vampire getting a sneak attack if they qualified as flanking.